# suitable collocation

Tags: collocation

Do you have any idea for better collocation?

So I chose decided to study chemical engineering at the university to pursue my passion since at high school we just studied **basic concepts**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe **basic concepts** to be perhaps the most suitable and common collocation in that context.

Alternatives include **fundamental concepts** and **the basics**.

Furthermore, I think your sentence will read better as:

> So I decided to study chemical engineering at the University in order to pursue my passion, since we only studied basic concepts in high school.